# How to configure GitLab CI config.toml so that output_limit works

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab project with the native CI set up, using a shared runner that I unfortunately do not have root access to. I am nonetheless the developer for the CI, so I am making do by messaging my sysadmin to update the `gitlab-runner` whenever I need changes/resets/etc.

I've run into trouble setting up the `config.toml` file in `etc/gitlab-runner/` to ensure the `output_limit` variable is high enough for all of my CI log output. I am following the documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html), but it seems to be missing a little bit of information as far as requirements for this file go.

How do I actually specify *which* runner I want to link to in the `[[runners]]` section of the config file? The `name` seems to be arbitrary, and the URL seems to have `/ci` added to the end everywhere I see examples on the internet -- do I need to add that, even if my GitLab URL doesn't include that? I am also not sure which token to use. Currently I am using the token that my shared runner is labeled as active beside in the Settings > CI/CD > Runners dropdown in my project settings.

Here is the content (some redacted) of my `config.toml`:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "arbitrary-name"
  url = "http://IP.IP.IP.IP"
  token = "<token-mentioned-above>"
  output_limit = 16000
```

But the output size of my CI output is still stuck at 4092 after a `gitlab-runner restart`. Do I need to include more than this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Work for me, here is the my toml file

```sh
[[runners]]
   name = "serv1"
   url = "http://ip"
   token = "token"
   output_limit = 50000000
```

Restart runner service

```sh
systemctl restart gitlab-runner
```